# change of one pointer affect other pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

How it is possible the komv->next become NULL on this code before the end of while loop?
I notice that become NULL after this line town->previous->next=town->next but i cant understand why this happened. Program terminated with segmentation fault.

```
komv=list->First;
        while ((komv->next)!=NULL)
        {      


            if(town->num>=komv->next->num)
                {   

                    town->previous->next=town->next;

                    if(town->next!=NULL)
                        town->next->previous=town->previous;        
                    town->next=komv->next;
                    town->previous=komv;
                    komv->next->previous=town; //  gdb say komv->next=NULL 
                    komv->next=town;    

                    break;                  
                }
            komv=komv->next;


        }
```

Comment: town is already a node in the list

Comment: this line: while ((komv->next)!=NULL) should be while (komv!=NULL)  then modify the rest of the loop to be based on the current linked list node.  then only step to the next node 'komv=komv->next;' at the end of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `komv` is the node preceding `town` in the list, then `town->previous == komv`.  If `town` is the last node then `town->next == NULL`.  When those are true at the same time, this:

```
                town->previous->next=town->next;
```

reduces to:

```
                komv->next = NULL;
```

In that case, it looks like there is no need to modify the list, so you could fix the problem by modifying your condition to

```
        if ((town != komv->next) && (town->num >= komv->next->num)) {
```

There might be a better solution, too, depending on what assumptions and behavior you want.  For example, if it would be acceptable to insert `town` *after* nodes having the same `num` instead of before, then you could simply use this condition:

```
        if (town->num > komv->next->num) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The only condition I can think of is if `town` is the last node of the list, then you get at the last iteration)

```
if (town->num >= komv->next->num) // komv is the previous to last element, so komv->next is town.
 {
   town->previous->next = town->next; // here, komv->next is changed to NULL.
   ...
```